# Update value in multidimensional array in Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, vue.js

I understand from the caveats portion of the Vue docs that updating a value in an array in the following manner will not work:

```
  this.arr[idx] = newVal
```

and that one should use `splice()`. I am using a 2D array to store grid data, and I am having a difficult time updating the value when a cell in the grid is clicked.

Here is my template:

```
  <tr
      v-for="(row, rowKey, index) in grid"
        :key="rowKey">
        <th
          class="row-col-label"
        >{{rowKey+1}}</th>
        <td
            v-for="(col, colKey, index) in row"
            :key="colKey"
            @click="selectCell(rowKey, colKey)"
            :class="{'selected' : cellSelected(rowKey, colKey)}"
        >
        {{col}}
        </td>
      </tr>
```

And here is the relevant code for the Vue component:

```
 created () {
  this.initColHead()
  this.createSpreadSheet()
 },
 data () {
  return {
   selected: '',
   grid: [],
   colHead: [' '],
   isSelected: false
 }
},
methods: {
 initColHead () {
   this.colHead.push(...'ABC'.split(''))
 },
 createSpreadSheet () {
   for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
     this.grid[i] = []
      for (let j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
       this.grid[i][j] = false
      }
   }
 },
selectCell (row, col) {
  this.isSelected = true
  console.log(`row ${row} col ${col}`)
  this.grid[row].splice(col, 1, true)
  for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
      console.log(this.grid[i][j])
    }
  }
},
cellSelected (row, col) {
  return (this.grid[row][col] === true)
}
}
```

So I am attempting to add a `true` value to the cell that is click at the given `row` `col` locations provided in the my `selectCell` method. However, the data in my grid is not updated to reflect the newly added value. How exactly do I update values in a multidimensional array in Vue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One method that works:

```
selectCell (row, col) {
  //make a copy of the row
  const newRow = this.grid[row].slice(0)
  // update the value
  newRow[col] = true
  // update it in the grid
  this.$set(this.grid, row, newRow)
},
```

Here is an example.

```js
console.clear()


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  created() {
    this.initColHead()
    this.createSpreadSheet()
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: '',
      grid: [],
      colHead: [' '],
      isSelected: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    initColHead() {
      this.colHead.push(...'ABC'.split(''))
    },
    createSpreadSheet() {
      for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        this.grid[i] = []
        for (let j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
          this.grid[i][j] = false
        }
      }
    },
    selectCell(row, col) {
      const newRow = this.grid[row].slice(0)
      newRow[col] = true
      this.$set(this.grid, row, newRow)
    },
    cellSelected(row, col) {
      return (this.grid[row][col] === true)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="(row, rowKey, index) in grid" :key="rowKey">
      <th class="row-col-label">{{rowKey+1}}</th>
      <td v-for="(col, colKey, index) in row" :key="colKey" @click="selectCell(rowKey, colKey)" :class="{'selected' : cellSelected(rowKey, colKey)}">
        {{col}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

If I think of something better I'll update later.

Comment: Thanks!. What I ended up doing is  this.grid = this.grid.map(el => el.splice()) in order to update the entire grid after setting the new value and it seems to be working; however, your solution looks a lot better.

Answer (score 4):

The difficulty is that you're building the array in a way that Vue does not make its rows reactive. You could build the array and then assign it to the data item as a whole so that Vue would make it reactive, or you can build the array (at last the rows) using `push`, which will make them reactive. Then you can modify individual elements using `splice`. Modifying Bert's example:

```js
console.clear()


new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  created() {
    this.initColHead()
    this.createSpreadSheet()
  },
  data() {
    return {
      selected: '',
      grid: [],
      colHead: [' '],
      isSelected: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    initColHead() {
      this.colHead.push(...'ABC'.split(''))
    },
    createSpreadSheet() {
      for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        this.grid.push([]);
        for (var j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
          this.grid[i].push(false);
        }
      }
    },
    selectCell(row, col) {
      this.grid[row].splice(col, 1, true);
    },
    cellSelected(row, col) {
      return (this.grid[row][col] === true)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="(row, rowKey, index) in grid" :key="rowKey">
      <th class="row-col-label">{{rowKey+1}}</th>
      <td v-for="(col, colKey, index) in row" :key="colKey" @click="selectCell(rowKey, colKey)" :class="{'selected' : cellSelected(rowKey, colKey)}">
        {{col}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Good catch! I didn't notice the implication of how the grid was built.

Comment: Very nice. Can you explain why using `push` works differently?

Comment: @MahmudAdam For the same reason that `splice` is recommended: it is one of the [mutation methods](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods) that Vue re-wrote for reactive arrays.